# How can i convert uppercase in lowercase inside a list?

Tags: python

```
def get_tokens(string):
    for char in string:
      if not char.isalpha():
        string = string.replace(char," ") 

    tokens=string.lower()
    tokens=list(string.split(" "))
    tokens=' '.join(list(string.split(" "))).split()

    return tokens

str1="Hello, my name is Julie3467#$#$!"

print(get_tokens(str1))
```

Current output: ['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Julie']

Goal: ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'julie']

Comment: `tokens=' '.join(list(string.split(" "))).split()`: You are *splitting, joining and then splitting*, which would be equivalent to *splitting*.

Comment: When you reach a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful answers and accept the best (even if you have to write it yourself).  This allows Stack Overflow to archive your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
tokens=string.lower()
tokens=list(string.split(" "))
```

You convert your string to lower-case, then immediately throw away that result, go back to the *original* string, and split the line.

Instead, split the result of `lower`:

```
tokens=list(string.lower().split(" "))
```

UPDATE:
Note Austin's comment as well; it's the same principle: you over-write the results of the previous statement.

Comment: Also, OP shouldn't use the second last line inside function. (Side note: Remove the cast to list).

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks Prune and Austin